# How to make an inherited method private in extended class

Tags: typescript, inheritance, private-methods

I want to make an inherited method private outside of the extended class in **Typescript**

Let's say I have two classes like this:

```js
class BaseClass{
    constructor(){}

    sayHello(){
        console.log('hello');
    }
}

class Class extends BaseClass{
    constructor(){
        super();
    }

    private sayHello(){  //I don't want to have to do this every time
        super.sayHello(); 
    }
}

let obj = new Class();
obj.sayHello();
```

I need to access the method `sayHello()` inside of 'Class' but it shouldn't be accessible from outside. I don't want to have to overwrite it every time I inherit.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. also, it's a bad idea because it violates the Liskov Substitution Principle https://stackify.com/solid-design-liskov-substitution-principle/

Comment: @M.Elkady it doesn't violate the Liskov Substitution Principle because using the accepted answer the method isn't accessible from outside in both cases (which is what I needed) and therefore doesn't change the behavior of the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `protected` access modifier. A protected member is accessible from derived classes but not from outside the class

```
class BaseClass{
    constructor(){}

    protected sayHello(){
        console.log('hello');
    }
}

class Class extends BaseClass{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.sayHello() // ok
    }
}

let obj = new Class();
obj.sayHello(); //err
```

Answer (score 3):

The keyword `protected` makes the method accessible only to extended classes and not to the outside.

```
class BaseClass {
    constructor() { }

    protected sayHello() {
        console.log('hello');
    }
}

class Class extends BaseClass {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    protected sayHello() {
        super.sayHello(); 
    }
}
```